# Instant preview in my own approved / made edits in questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

**SCENARIO**
I usually handle with new users questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731279/how-can-i-use-if-statement-in-join-query-in-codeigniter) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731391/please-help-trying-to-make-simple-tic-tac-toe-app-with-android-studio-getting) with really bad code formatting.

- If there is an edit, I check it, and *approve* it or *improve* it.
- If there is no edit I try to fix the question for better readability.

**PROBLEM**
When done this, I'm still not able to see the question edited because there is the pending edit approval requests... ok... *fair enough* :).
 But... 
**I still want to answer the question!!! And it's readability** (for being polite xD) **is ZERO**... 
So what I do?

- Mark as favorite and wait till edit is approved?
- Reload page continously till edit is approved?
- Use the code formatted by myself locally?
- Use the edit of someone else to read the code propperly?

I find this are not really handy sollutions, so here comes my:

**FEATURE REQUEST**
As long as I approved or make an edit, I can confirm **is useful**, at least for me *of course may not be for other users, so it's great to have the edit votes.* So... wouldn't be useful to see **my own or approved edits in questions** in order to make easy to answer?

Of course this will need to have some limitations, but I think may be a good idea in order to get faster answers from interested people.

Comment: Bad examples? You haven't even started to answer those two? And they're readable as they are? Also if you hit *Improve edit* then the question is not edit locked afterwards.

Comment: Actually I prefered to write this question than answer first one second one I flagged and commented it